# Not able to parse joda DateTime fields into XML in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am having a org.joda.time.DateTime field in my API response object. The application gives proper response as json but when the Accept header is set to application/xml it fails with  error

> Caused by:
>
> `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException`: Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.abc.xyz.dto.requestqueuelist.RequestByIdDto["dateCreated"])

But I do have the  [jackson-datatype-joda](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda) library in my project.
The issue started in recent versions and jackson version in the project is 2.14.3.
What could be the reason for this issue and how to resolve this?

Comment: Why Joda and not `java.time.*`?

Comment: Joda has been used in the application and it used to work.Things broke recently.So need to figure out why it went wrong with Joda first

Comment: Probably a good time to switch

Comment: Can you show us a reproducible example? Did you also register the Joda module as a bean? In which version did it work for you?

Comment: I have seen it working when the jackson version was 2.13.4, currently it is 2.14.3.
Springboot version is 3.0.9.
And yes Joda module is registered.